# How to remove text between two keywords in a textfile

Tags: text-processing, xml

Context : GNU/Linux Ubuntu.

I've a file made of thousands of lines and I'd like to have a script that will remove some lines between 2 specific keywords.
Initial file is like:

```
bla bla
...
bla bla
keyword1
bla bla
...
bla bla
keyword2
bla bla
...
bla bla
```

I would like to keep all file except the part between `keyword1` and `keyword2`.

Let's consider that `keyword1` and `keyword2` appear once and only once in the file; these keywords may be preceded or followed by other characters on their lines like spaces or `<` or `>`

The lines with the keywords on them look like this (they are actually XML-based files):

```xml
<keyword2>
```

The keywords can be kept in the file or be removed along with the enclosed text, I'm fine with both outcomes.

I did not find out how to proceed using `grep`. I'm not familiar with `awk`; could it make it?

Comment: Let's consider that keyword1 and keyword2 appear once and only once in the file; these keywords may be preceded or followed by other characters on their lines like spaces or '<' or '>' => We can have a line like :       <keyword2> ; keywords can be kept in the file.

Comment: Follow-up question: Since you are explicitly using `<keyword1>` as example, are you actually working with structured data (as in HTML or XML)? If so, using a dedicated parser like `xmlstarlet` is preferable to using line-oriented text-processing tools like `grep`/`sed`/`awk`.

Comment: "keywords can be kept in the file.": is that a requirement or are you saying you are fine both with the keywords being kept and with the keywords being removed?

Comment: Yes, it is an XML based file.  I'm fine with both results (with or without keywords in the result).

Comment: If your file is an XML document, then please post a representative XML document for us to work with.  XML is easy to work with given the correct tools.  `sed` is not the correct tool for working with XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put your sample text into the file `file`, and tested also with `<>` around the keywords.

This command with `sed` removes the keywords

```
$ < file sed '/keyword1/,/keyword2/d'
bla bla
...
bla bla
bla bla
...
bla bla
```

This command with `sed` preserves the keywords

```
$ < file sed -n -e '1,/keyword1/p' -e '/keyword2/,$p'
bla bla
...
bla bla
<keyword1>
<keyword2>
bla bla
...
bla bla
```

Comment: Thank you a lot sudodus.  Your solution is perfect for me.

Comment: You are welcome @llr22300 :-)

Comment: If these are XML node names, then there is nothing stopping there from being another `keyword1` node before the one you show in your example, in which case you will get unexpected results.  Also, since XML is not line-oriented, you will not be able to handle the case with `<keyword1>data<keyword2>`.

Comment: @they, *True*, but the OP states "Let's consider that keyword1 and keyword2 appear once and only once in the file" and also implies that they appear on separate lines. An advantage with `sed` (and other basic tools) is that it works well also with huge files.

Comment: @llr22300 If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne '.put unless /keyword1/ ^fff^ /keyword2/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
bla bla
...
bla bla
keyword1
bla bla
...
bla bla
keyword2
bla bla
...
bla bla
```

Sample Output:

```
bla bla
...
bla bla
keyword1
keyword2
bla bla
...
bla bla
```

Briefly, Raku's `-ne` command line flags tell Raku to execute code without autoprinting. Printing is accomplished via first instruction `.put` ('print-using-terminator', i.e. newline). The `.` dot preceding `put` is short for `$_.put` wherein `$_` represents the topic variable (in this case, containing data from the input line).

The `fff` instruction is Raku's sed-like "flip-flop" operator, which turns ON/OFF based upon the two surrounding regexes. In Raku (and Perl5), `unless` is an alias to `if not`. Finally, the `^` carets surrounding `fff` to give `^fff^` tell Raku to exclude the endpoints.

Because `unless` is a negation, `^fff^` negates the exclusion of endpoints, which preserves `keyword1` and `keyword2` in the output. Using `fff` instead of `^fff^` deletes `keyword1` and `keyword2` from the output.

(Note here, that if you really want to parse an `XML` file, then one-liner Raku solutions can be crafted using Raku's `XML` module).

https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=Raku+%5BXML%5D
https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML
https://raku.org

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. I keep it in mind. Solution with sed fits my need so far.

Answer (score 0):

The previous suggestion about sed's won't give expected results when the "keyword" is not the only word in the line. If you want to extract a text between any two words from any paragraph regardless of their positions, you will need Perl, particularly [Perl's File Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp)

For example, let's say we have this text:

```
Sir Arthur Conan Doyle was born on May 22, 1859, in Edinburgh. 
He studied medicine at the University of Edinburgh and began to write stories while he was a student. 
Over his life he produced more than 30 books, 150 short stories, poems, plays, and essays across a wide range
of genres. 
His most famous creation is the detective Sherlock Holmes, who he introduced in his first novel, A Study in Scarlet (1887). 
This was followed in 1889 by an historical novel, Micah Clarke.
```

My keywords here are "medicine" and "Holmes" respectively.

The results with sed will delete exactly the first and the last lines from the paragraph. While the expected result should also remove the part of the sentence that is before and including `medicine`, plus after and including `Holmes`.

Let's try Perl's File Slurp:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 'push @a,/medicine(.*?)Holmes/s;END{print "@a"}' myparagraph.txt
```

The output:

```
at the University of Edinburgh and began to write stories while he was a student. 
Over his life he produced more than 30 books, 150 short stories, poems, plays, and essays across a wide range
of genres. 
His most famous creation is the detective Sherlock
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. I keep it in mind. Solution with sed fits my need so far.

Answer (score 0):

As we don't have a real XML document to work with, I'm going to assume that the document in question looks somewhat like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <entry>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <number>133</number>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>Mary</name>
    <number>123</number>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>Stan</name>
    <number>233</number>
  </entry>
</root>
```

The task is also a bit unclear, so I will show how to

1. Delete one of the `entry` nodes given a `name` value.
2. Change the `number` value for one `entry` node, given a `name` value.
3. Remove the contents of one of the `entry` nodes, given a `name` value.

This will first be done using the reasonably common command-line XML parser `xmlstarlet` and then the lesser-known `xq` (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), a wrapper around the well-known JSON parser `jq`.

First, using XPath syntax with `xmlstarlet`:

1. Deleting Stan:

   ```bsh
   xmlstarlet ed \
       --var name '"Stan"' \
       --delete '//entry[name = $name]' file.xml
   ```

   This takes the XPath string `"Stan"`, assigns it to the internal variable `$name`, and uses it to pick out the `entry` node that has that particular `name` value.  The `entry` node may be located anywhere in the document since we use `//entry` rather than a specific path such as `/root/entry` to find it.

   The found node is deleted by `xmlstarlet`, and the resulting XML document is written to standard output.

   The resulting document:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <entry>
       <name>Joe</name>
       <number>133</number>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <name>Mary</name>
       <number>123</number>
     </entry>
   </root>
   ```
2. Changing Stan's number to 455:

   ```bsh
   xmlstarlet ed \
       --var name '"Stan"' \
       --var value '455' \
       --update '//entry[name = $name]/number' \
       --expr '$value' file.xml
   ```

   This is similar to the first command in that it selects the `entry` node that we're interested in using the internal variable `$name`, containing an XPath string.  Rather than deleting the found node(s), it updates the `number` sub-node using the provided value in the internal `$value` variable.

   The resulting document:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <entry>
       <name>Joe</name>
       <number>133</number>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <name>Mary</name>
       <number>123</number>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <name>Stan</name>
       <number>455</number>
     </entry>
   </root>
   ```
3. Emptying Stan's record:

   ```bsh
   xmlstarlet ed \
       --var name '"Stan"' \
       --update '//entry[name = $name]' \
       --value '' file.xml
   ```

   Again, this shows that we may empty a node by updating its value to an empty string.

   The resulting document:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <entry>
       <name>Joe</name>
       <number>133</number>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <name>Mary</name>
       <number>123</number>
     </entry>
     <entry/>
   </root>
   ```

The `xq` wrapper around `jq` parses and transcodes the XML document into JSON.  It then applies a `jq` expression to the generated JSON document and optionally translates it back to XML.

Given the document at the start of this answer, even though the input is an XML document, `xq` will internally work with a JSON document that looks like this:

```json
{
  "root": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "name": "Joe",
        "number": "133"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mary",
        "number": "123"
      },
      {
        "name": "Stan",
        "number": "233"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

1. Deleting Stan:

   ```bsh
   xq --xml-output \
       --arg name 'Stan' \
       'del(.root.entry[] | select(.name == $name))' file.xml
   ```

   This uses the `del()` function of `jq` to delete the given path.  The path is found by selecting the element(s) from the `.root.entry` array with a `.name` key with the value given by `$name`, an internal variable that we set on the command line.
2. Changing Stan's number to 455:

   ```bsh
   xq --xml-output \
       --arg name 'Stan' \
       --arg value 455 \
       '(.root.entry[] | select(.name == $name)).number |= $value' file.xml
   ```

   This is similar to the previous expression, but rather than deleting the selected node(s) with `del()`, we access the `.number` key and update its value using the internal variable `$value`.
3. Emptying Stan's record:

   ```bsh
   xq --xml-output \
       --arg name 'Stan' \
       '(.root.entry[] | select(.name == $name)) |= null' file.xml
   ```

   Again, we use a similar expression that selects the node(s) we're interested in and then updates it with `null` to empty it.  Using `empty` in place of `null` would delete the node, so that's another way of achieving the same result as under the first point just above.

The main difference between these `xmlstarlet` and `xq`/`jq` expressions is that we're using an absolute path with `xq`, while we use `//` in the XPath expression with `xmlstarlet` to search for the nodes we're interested in recursively.  You may do recursive searching with `xq` as well, but it's a bit more tricky, and the example we chose to work with here doesn't require it.